# Is React-native has native or not component looks like Development menu (iOS)?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Is React-native has native or not component looks like Development menu on iOS (cmd+d)? Or How I can implement it? I want to add 2 items with link (sharing) and just 'cancel' button.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please edit your question

Comment: Yes that's called an "Action sheet" you can find it in React native documentation and also there are lots of library available for it you can use from it.Thank You

Comment: @SwapnilPanchal, thanks a lot. already have found it

Comment: Okay that's cool